# SQL Select Query on a Combination of Condition for May Cases

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch the details from a sql table on a combination of particular condition but for many cases.Suppose I have a **table Employee** such as:

```
  username | user_id | Forename | Surname
  ash      |  a1     |  Ashish  | Sharma
  ashK     |  a2     |  Ashish  | Kumar
  piy      |  p1     |  Piyush  | Sharma
  piyA     |  p2     |  Piyush  | Kumar
  raj      |  r1     |  Rajat   | Sharma
  rajD     |  r2     |  Rajat   | Kumar
```

Now I want to fetch the details on the basis of Forename and Surname like

```
  username | user_id | Forename | Surname
  ash      |  a1     | Ashish   |  Sharma
  piy      |  p2     | Piyush   |  Kumar
  raj      |  r1     | Rajat    |  Sharma
```

Currently I am using the query:

```
SELECT 
      * 
FROM Employee
WHERE forename IN ('Ashish','Piyush','Rajat') 
     AND surname IN ('Sharma','Kumar','Sharma')
```

But the above query provides me all the rows i.e. it fetches `Piyush Sharma` row also which i don't want to capture.

Please suggest if you require any more details.

Comment: `WHERE CONCATENATE(forename, "|", surname) IN ("First|Last", ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CONCAT()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm)

```
  select * 
  from Employee 
  where CONCAT(forename, surname) in 
          ('AshishSharma','PiyushKumar','RajatSharma')
```

Comment: The above query gave me an error invalid number of arguements

Comment: I can't vote up due to reputation.and how to mark it answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Try separating your `WHERE` clause conditions. See my query below:

```
SELECT 
      * 
FROM Employee
WHERE 
     (forename ='Ashish' AND surname='Sharma') OR
     (forename ='Piyush' AND surname='Rajat') OR
     (forename ='Kumar' AND surname='Sharma')
```